# Loop Workflow over users in Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, approval-process

I would like to create a workflow for a library which will loop over all users from a permissions group (`Approval Users`) in order and assign a task to the users. If any of the users rejects the changes, the loop should break.

I'm familiar with adding the loop blocks to SharePoint Designer, but I'm not sure how to loop through the Users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use a `Start a Task Process` action and not a loop step. From the Task process you are able to control the assignment of tasks (just as with the `assign task` action, but with additional settings for controlling the group). Within the task process settings you can assign the tasks to a designated SharePoint Group.